# How to set icon of a button in ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an icon button and i need to change the icon once user presses the button. I used to change it in the content page before, now if i dont set the value at the top there is no icon what so ever and if i set it in my load method the picture wont check, but if i set it the the top i cant change it either.

```
private string _playPauseButton = IconsFont.Volume2;
 public string PlayPauseButton
        {
            get { return _playPauseButton; }
            set
            {
                _playPauseButton = value;

                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(_playPauseButton));
            }
        }

 public ViewModel()
            : base(listenCultureChanges: true)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await LoadAllDataForDictionary()).Wait();
            PlayPauseCommand = new Command(() => StartOrStopPlaying());
        }


 private void StartOrStopPlaying()
        {
            if (!viewDisabled)
            {

                var paused = LangUpDictionaryPlayer.PlayPause();
                if (paused)
                {

                    LangUpDictionaryPlayer.SetTrack(_word.Id);
                    _playPauseButton = IconsFont.AudioPause;

                }
                else
                {
                    _playPauseButton = IconsFont.Volume2;

                }
            }

        }
```

Also 
what difference would i make by doing this

```
 public string PlayPauseButton
        {
            set
            {
                _playPauseButton = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();


            }
            get => _playPauseButton;
        }
```

INsted of what i have?

Comment: NotifyPropertyChanged should use the name of the PUBLIC property, not the internal private backing field

Comment: ok, i have changed it, but it didnt solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using the Public in the code

PlayPauseButton = IconsFont.AudioPause;